# python- split() doesn't work inside __init__

Tags: python, split, wsgi

I am writing code to serve a html file using wsgi.When I write a straight forward function I get no error like :

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import os
   ...
   ...
def app(environ, start_response):
    path_info = environ["PATH_INFO"]
    resource = path_info.split("/")[1] #I get no error here the split works totally fine.
```

Now when I try to put the code inside a class I get error NoneType has no attribute split. 
Perhaps the `environ` inside `__init__` doesn't get initialised , that's why it split returns nothing. Following is the file in which my class `Candy` resides :

```
import os
class Candy:
    def __init__(self):
            #self.environ = environ
            #self.start = start_response
            self.status = "200 OK"
            self.headers = []

    def __call__(self , environ , start_response):
        self.environ = environ
        self.start = start_response

    #headers = []
    def content_type(path):
        if path.endswith(".css"):
            return "text/css"
        else:
            return "text/html"


    def app(self):
        path_info = self.environ["PATH_INFO"]
        resource = path_info.split("/")[1]

        #headers = []
        self.headers.append(("Content-Type", content_type(resource)))

        if not resource:
            resource = "login.html"
        resp_file = os.path.join("static", resource)

        try:
            with open(resp_file, "r") as f:
                resp_file = f.read()
        except Exception:
            self.start("404 Not Found", self.headers)
            return ["404 Not Found"]

        self.start("200 0K", self.headers)
        return [resp_file]
```

Following is the `server.py` file where I invoke my make_server :

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from candy import Candy
#from app import candy_request

candy_class = Candy()

httpd = make_server('localhost', 8000, candy_class.app)
print "Serving HTTP on port 8000..."

# Respond to requests until process is killed
httpd.serve_forever()

# Alternative: serve one request, then exit
#httpd.handle_request()
```

Any help ? How to get this error sorted and am I right in my assumption?

Comment: `NoneType has no attribute split` means that `path_info` and thus `self.environ["PATH_INFO"]` is `None`. This has nothing to do with `split`.

Comment: how do you instantiate the class ? with the same parameters as for the first function ?

Comment: @Alex Hall That's exactly my assumption . I have written it too. How to get it sorted?

Comment: Well, I think it's impossible for use to say for sure, since you haven't provided the data, but the simple guess would be that `self.environ` has `"PATH_INFO"` mapped to None.

Comment: you need to include the code that calls (instantiates) the class.

Comment: more portable: `path_info.split(os.sep)`

Comment: Sorry, but where is `app` method actually called? Your class looks odd - normally, it's not `__init__` that receives `environ` and `start_response`, but `__call__` (or it's `__init__` but there is an `__iter__` method). Check PEP-333, it has some examples.

Comment: @drdaeman Ok may be that is the problem. Thanks , I will see and come back .

Comment: Also, check what exactly you're using as your app (i.e. check your `make_server` invocation) - whenever it's a *class* or its *instance* you're passing. If it's an instance - you need to implement `__call__` (and receive `environ` there). If it's a class - your `__init__` is generally OK, but you need `__iter__` (please show how you're calling `self.app(...)` there).

Comment: @drdaeman I have included both the files , please see them. I am a new diver into this wsgi world .

Comment: Based on your response to @Alex Hall...  If `self.environ["PATH_INFO"]` returns `None` it means that you have not set the environmental variable `$PATH_INFO`.  This needs to be set when the program runs.

Comment: @0decimal0: I see. That's still incorrect. Add `return self.app()` as a last line of your `__call__` method, and replace `candy_class.app` with just `candy_class` in `make_server`. Then it should work. I'll try to write a more detailed answer, explaining what's wrong with your setup and how it all works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain what you're doing wrong here, let's start with simple concepts - what a WSGI application is.

WSGI application is just a callable that receives a request environment, and a callback function that starts a response (sends status line and headers back to user). Then, this callable must return one or more strings, that constitute the response body.

In the simplest form, that you have working it's just

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/plain")])
    return "hello, world"

make_server('localhost', 8000, app).serve_forever()
```

Whenever a request comes, `app` function gets called, it starts the response and returns a string (or it could return an iterable of multiple strings, e.g. `["hello, ", "world"]`)

Now, if you want it to be a class, it works like this:

```
 class MyApp(object):
     def __init__(self):
         pass

     def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
         start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/plain")])
         return "something"

 app = MyApp()
 make_server("localhost", 8000, app).serve_forever()
```

In this case, the callable is `app`, and it's actually `__call__` method of `Caddy` class *instance*.

When request comes, `app.__call__` gets called (`__call__` is the magic method that turns your class instance in a callable), and otherwise it works exactly the same as the `app` function from the first example. Except that you have a class instance (with `self`), so you can do some pre-configuration in the `__init__` method. Without doing anything in `__init__` it's useless. E.g., a more realistic example would be this:

```
 class MyApp(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.favorite_color = "blue"

     def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
         start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/plain")])
         return "my favorite color is {}".format(self.favorite_color)
 ...
```

Then, there's another thing. Sometimes you want a streaming response, generated over time. Maybe it's big, or maybe it takes a while. That's why WSGI applications can return an iterable, rather than just a string.

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]))
    yield "This was a triumph\n"
    time.sleep(1)
    yield "I'm making a note here\n"
    time.sleep(1)
    yield "HUGE SUCCESS\n"

make_server("localhost", 8000, app).serve_forever()
```

This function returns a *generator* that returns text, piece by piece. Although your browser may not always show it like this, but try running `curl http://localhost:8000/`.

Now, the same with classes would be:

```
class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self, environ, start_response):
        self.environ = environ
        self.start = start_response

    def __iter__(self):
        self.start("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]))
        yield "This was a triumph\n"
        time.sleep(1)
        yield "I'm making a note here\n"
        time.sleep(1)
        yield "HUGE SUCCESS\n"

make_server("localhost", 8000, MyApp).serve_forever()
```

Here, you pass `MyApp` (the class) as a application callable - which it is. When request comes it gets called, it's like someone had written `MyApp(environ, start_response)` somewhere, so `__init__` starts and creates an instance for this specific request. Then, as the instance is iterated, `__iter__` starts to produce a response. After it's done, the instance is discarded.

Basically, that's it. Classes here are only convenience closures that hold data. If you don't need them, don't use classes, use plain functions - *flat is better than nested.*

---

Now, about your code.

What your code uses for callable is `Candy().app`. This doesn't work because it doesn't even made to receive `environ` and `start_response` it will be passed. It should probably fail with 500 error, saying something like `app() takes 1 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

I assume the code in your question is modified after you got that `NoneType has no attribute split` issue, and you had passed something to the `__init__` when creating `candy_instance = Candy()` when your `__init__` still had 2 arguments (3 with `self`). Not even sure what exactly it was - it should've failed earlier.

Basically, you passed the wrong objects to `make_server` and your class was a mix of two different ideas.

I suggest to check my examples above (and read PEP-333), decide what you actually need, and structure your `Candy` class like that.

- If you just need to return something on every request, and you don't have a persistent state - you don't need a class at all.
- If you need a persistent state (config, or, maybe, a database connection) - use a class instance, with `__call__` method, and make that `__call__` return the response.
- If you need to respond in chunks, use either a generator function, or a class with `__iter__` method. Or a class with `__call__` that `yields` (just like a function).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was really helpful thanks. I used class just to see how it works that way plus I thought when the code gets bigger you need abstraction don't you? Just call the instance and call whatever method in it .

Comment: I got one more problem though , the code I have uploaded here has a content-type method , when it is standalone it works fine , the customized .css files are accessed but when I use it inside the class the files are not accessible but just the plain html , any insights?

Comment: @0decimal0: Unless I'm mistaken, your `self.headers` grows on every `__call__`, because you never clear it. You don't need `headers` to be an attribute of the `Candy` class (that way, you share it between the requests), a local variable is better. And then you spew a lot of `Content-Type` headers, and browser gets confused.

Comment: You are amazingly cool, really. You solved all my problems and opened almost every nut and bolt of my brain in a single conversation . I made the `headers` and `content-type` method local and it went smooth. Thanks a ton once again :)

Comment: @0decimal0: Thanks! But don't forget about `status` as well - it's also request-local thing. Just consider a case that you'll possibly run your code on some multithreaded server (e.g. gunicorn), instead of `wsgiref.simple_server`, and multiple concurrent requests will mess it up for each other. That is, if you use a class instance, only keep in the class stuff that matters across the requests. And if you don't have anything - you don't need a class yet (I'd suggest to value simplicity and keep it a plain and simple function - then wrap it as a class when you'll actually need it that way).

Comment: Ah, sorry, you've edited your code already and `self.status` is already gone, remaining only in `__init__`. My bad, I haven't noticed it.